# Is it possible to automatically switch active unit in a group after cast in Dota 2?

Tags: dota-2, keyboard

Suppose I have several units selected (ilusions, meepos, etc.). I want to cast an ability of first unit, switch to second, cast ability of the second, switch to third, etc.

Is it possible to make all switching here automatic? So I press cast-cast-cast-... only, not cast-switch-cast-switch-cast-switch-...

Comment: The suggested duplicate is NOT the same. This question is asking if you can automatically switch active unit after casting a spell. The  duplicate is asking if one can cast a shared spell from all units at the same time.

Comment: @gitsitgo it IS the same if you take a look at the accepted answer.
The section "Manually" is the exact answer to this question.